# VSPackage: How to track a successful commit and push event?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, version-control, listener

Cheers, everyone! Hope you can help.

I'm developing a Visual Studio extension (VSPackage) in C# which needs to listen to a successful 'commit and push' or 'sync' event to update the gridview. Any ideas on how to implement a C# listener of a 'commit and push' or 'sync' event in VS?

P.S. I'd love to provide you with a piece of code of mine, but I've no idea whatsoever how to do that and Google hasn't been of any help.

Comment: To format text as code, place four spaces before the start of its line. To format inline text as code, enclose it in backticks. Also see [Formatting Help](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting).

Comment: Thanks, Ben. Apparently, I was dead asleep when I was formulating the question. What I meant to say in my P.S. is that I've no idea how to implement a C# listener of a 'commit and push' or 'sync' event in VS whatsoever, thus, I have no code to demonstrate in my question. Fortunately, I do know how to paste code in stackoevrflow ;)